# Saved File not present in internal storage

Tags: android

i want to save a view, when i run the app everything is working fine, but i am unable to find saved file/s in the internal storage of the phone. Any help would be appreciated as i am new and unable to sort out what is going wrong . here is my code

```
public void saveMe(View v) {
    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    // set prompt.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialog);


    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            final String fileName = userInput.getText().toString();
            final View view1=findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); // The view that you want to save as an image

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view1.getWidth(), view1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view1.draw(c);

            if(fileName.length() == 0)

                Toast.makeText(EidCardFinal.this,"Please Enter File Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else{

            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);

            if (file.exists())
                Toast.makeText(EidCardFinal.this,"File Already Exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                try{
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    Toast.makeText(EidCardFinal.this,"File Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


            }



        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

}

Comment: The location returned by Context.getFilesDir() is normally private the the application and difficult to examine from anything else, except on an Emulator or engineering device where ADBD runs as root.  You might want to consider using the External Storage instead for simplicity.

Comment: well, i have tried with many different combinations (other than context.getFilesdir()) by searching this forum and other platforms but unfortunately nothing worked. Strange part (for me) is when i enter the file name that i have already entered, i successfully got the message as mentioned in Toast.makeText and this confuses me, because it means that file is already there, but where????? wait for any solution and after than will definitely opt out for external storage.

Comment: The file is in a location where it is, by design, difficult or impossible to access it with anything but the app which owns it.  When you say you have tried many different things, that just makes your question nearly impossible to answer, since it turns it into a lot of non-specific questions which each lack the details to be answerable.

Comment: "i have tried many different things" means that instead of getting dir using the method above i have tried with the specific path and file name as well but all in vain. Anyways thank you very much for replying, may be i am unable to describe my problem.will go for external storage.

Comment: Most likely you *are* saving the file, but are *by design intention of Android* unable to access it with any tool other than the program which owns it.  External storage is generally better for things you want to export.